# WPF RichTextBox/FlowDocument do something on specific text added

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I'm attempting to extend a RichTextBox in order to add some functionality, and need the ability to call a function when certain characters are entered. For instance, every time a user enters a ';', I want to call that function.

I know that I can add a `OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)` method to the `TextChanged` event, but that doesn't seem to really solve my problem, since I can't seem to find a good way to tell what the changes were. I could check the whole document for ';' every time the text changes, but that seems to be a bit inefficient to me.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown.aspx)

```
private void richTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Oem1)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that... Thanks!